# Passing variables to Symfony2 service constructor

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I have a Symfony2 application (a bridge to third party API) consisting mostly of console commands. Each console command takes an "organizationId" argument which is used to resolve various options of the API, such as API key, url, available languages etc. 90% of services in the application use these parameters either for calling the API, or for fetching/storing data in the local database.

I use Symfony DI to construct the services, and each service has public method `setOrganization(Organization $organization)` which is called after getting the service. E.g. (simplified code):

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $organization = $this
        ->getContainer()
        ->get('doctrine')
        ->getRepository('CoreBundle:Organization')
        ->find($input->getArgument('organizationId'));

    $personService = $this->getContainer()
        ->get('person')
        ->setOrganization($organization); // I want to get rid of this
    $personService->doStuff();
}
```

Service definition:

```
person:
    class: AppBundle\Services\Person
    arguments: ["@buzz", "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@organization_settings_resolver", "%media_service%"]
```

I am looking for a way to refactor code so that I don't need to call `setOrganization()` whenever I use any service. Is it possible to pass an object or a command line parameter to the constructor without passing the whole service container?
Maybe there should be a different approach, e.g. something like `security.token_storage` layer, which would store something like "session information" but in a console way?
What would be the best architectural and Symfony-way solution here?

Comment: Short answer is no, you can't pass args to the container.  You might try using command events (http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/events.html) which would allow you to make a listener to setup the person service before the command execute is called.  Similar to what the kernel events do.  Never tried it myself.  Might not be worth the effort.

Answer (score 3):

In a service definition, you can call a method of the service in the initilisation, thus you can avoid calling it after getting it :

```
person:
    class: AppBundle\Services\Person
    arguments: ["@buzz", "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@organization_settings_resolver", "%media_service%"]
    calls:
        - [ setOrganization,[ @your_organization ] ]
```

This is if your_organisation is a defined and available service

Comment: In this case organization depends on input arguments and thus is not available as a service.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the organisation a parameter of the `->doStuff()` method?

This way, you should not need to call the setOrganisation anymore and remove the possibility of calling doStuff without setting the organisation first.